# Could Design Patterns for NoSql DBs be used to model Firestore Firebase database?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, neo4j, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to model my Firestore database in the most efficient way. I am a front end developer relying on Firebase for my backend. Is it ok if I study best practices applied to MongoDB or Neo4j? Or the concepts behind those are totally different?

Answer (score 1):

Graph databases like neo4j are not really like NoSQL database.  What you learn for graph databases does not really apply.

NoSQL data modeling is similar for many databases, but they are each going to have their own strengths and weaknesses, and you'll have to learn and adapt to those.  I don't see that there is any way around that.  The bottom line is to take advantage of the structuring options you've been given to suit your expected queries.  If you don't know what kind of queries you're performing, you may not be able to effectively use your database for an actual product.